# How can I improve my planet's approval in Galactic Civilizations 2?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

I have a lot of planets that have an approval rate of 50 and. A huge number of it always comes from "population".

What does it mean? Say for example this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8HEM.jpg What can I do to improve my approval?

Comment: I made your image into an actual image. The two in the link looked identical to me. Let me know if that's not okay!

Comment: No, it isn't. The second image had a pop-up with infos what's causing the decrease in approval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to improve your approval:

1. Lower your tax rate.  The higher the taxes the lower your approval.
2. Control your population.  Overpopulation leads to worse approval levels.
3. Build some [Entertainment Centers](http://galciv.wikia.com/wiki/Entertainment_Center).

The reason your approval is low is due reason #2.  20 billion (and you are really close at 19.75b) is roughly the cutoff point for managing approval.  Any more population and its not worth the extra effort to maintain approval.

Comment: And yes, that DOES mean that you need to be *very* careful with upgrading planetary farms, especially ones on boosted tiles. ..

Comment: Yea, I figured out later on about 20 billion was the "cap". Had to destroy all the extra farms that were upgraded by the governor and placed stock-markets instead. Monies, all the monies in de galaxy is moi!